# Jpg encoding with Java

Tags: java, image-processing, jpeg, javax.imageio

I stumbled onto this problem today, let me explain the issue:

I have this Java web application that deals with a lot of image files. It only allows JPGs files (company policy I guess...). The files are stored on some fixed location, and the upload process and thumbnail generation is going pretty well. The pictures are shown using a Java class because the company doesn´t want to show the path.

The thing is that some of the pictures shown are dark; not all black, just a little darker than the original uploaded file. I checked the uploaded files and thumbnails and they look well, they are not darkened at all.

This is where the thing gets weird: I tested on localhost, and the pictures display correctly, when I test on the server they look dark. The only difference between the two is that on localhost I work on Windows and the test server is Linux. Both use JBOSS 4.2.0.

This is the method that does the trick:

```
protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {              

    String ruta = rutaBase + File.separator;
    String fileName=(String)request.getParameter("fileName");

    if (fileName==null) 
        fileName="";
    if (!fileName.equals("")) {
        RemoteFileClient oRemoteFileClient = new RemoteFileClient();
        ServletOutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
        if (oRemoteFileClient.isAlive()) {
            String file2download=ruta+fileName;
            byte[] contenido=oRemoteFileClient.downloadFile(file2download);                 
            if (contenido!=null) {
                String myContentType="";
                boolean isImage=false;
                String nombreFichero = fileName.toLowerCase();
                String extension = nombreFichero.substring(nombreFichero.lastIndexOf(".")+1);
                if (extension.equals("jpg") ||
                    extension.equals("jpeg") ||
                    extension.equals("JPG") ||
                    extension.equals("JPEG")) {
                    myContentType="image/jpeg";
                    isImage=true;
                } 
                else if (extension.equals("gif") || extension.equals("GIF")) {
                    myContentType="image/gif";
                    isImage=true;
                } 
                else if (extension.equals("png") || extension.equals("PNG")) {
                    myContentType="image/png";
                    isImage=true;
                } 
                else if (extension.equals("doc") || extension.equals("DOC") || 
                            extension.equals("rtf") || extension.equals("RTF")) {
                    myContentType="application/msword";
                } 
                else if (extension.equals("bin") || 
                           extension.equals("exe")) {
                    myContentType="application/octet-stream";
                } 
                else if (extension.equals("zip")) {
                    myContentType="application/x-zip";
                } 
                else if (extension.equals("pdf")) {
                    myContentType="application/pdf";
                } 
                else if (extension.equals("txt")) {
                    myContentType="text/plain";
                } 
                else if (extension.equals("xls")) {
                    myContentType="application/ms-excel";
                } 
                else if (extension.equals("ppt")) {
                    myContentType="application/ms-powerpoint";
                }
                response.setContentType(myContentType);
                if (isImage) {
                    BufferedImage im = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(contenido));                           
                    JPEGImageEncoder encoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(output);
                    //JPEGEncodeParam param = encoder.getDefaultJPEGEncodeParam(im);
                    //param.setQuality(1.0f,true);
                    //encoder.encode(im, param);
                    encoder.encode(im);
                } else {
                    output.write(contenido);
                }
                output.flush();
                output.close();
            }
        } 
        else{
            output.println("No se puede conectar con el servidor de archivos<br>");
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Then, on the JSPs where I need to display the pictures I just do this:

```
<img class="pic" alt="Foto destacada" src="descargarFichero.do?fileName=<c:out value="${foto.nombre}"/>/thumb_<c:out value="${foto.nombre}"/>"/>
```

The action "descargarFichero.do" calls the method I posted.

My wild guess is that there is some issue with the JPG encoding but I don't know much about these things so I gladly hear (read) your suggestions.

Remember, just some of the pictures are showing dark, not all of them, I'm looking the troubled files but haven't found anything suspicious yet.

Thanks a lot

P.S. Another method you might need

```
public byte[] downloadFile(String filename) {
    byte downloadfile[] = null;
    try {
        byte buffer[];
        File file = new File(filename);
        if(file.exists() || (!file.isDirectory())) {
            buffer = new byte[(int)file.length()];
            BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
            input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            input.close();
            downloadfile = buffer;
        } else {
            //break MISSING_BLOCK_LABEL_65;
            return null;
        }
    } catch(Exception exception) {
        //System.out.println("FileImpl: " + e.getMessage());
        exception.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return downloadfile;
}
```

Comment: Any reason for not returning the file as it is? All modern browsers can handle gif, jpg and png. So why do you load them in your servlet to re-encode them as jpg?

Comment: Side notes: you can replace your two first `if` with `if(fileName != null)` directly. If you use `fileName.toLowerCase()`, you don't need to check if the string is equal to `jpg || JPG`, but only to `jpg`.

Comment: Perhaps it's an connection issue over the network?? Did you run any tests to see if it's the reason?

Comment: This sounds like an issue with gamma, and the color spaces of some images.

Comment: You would have to show us what `oRemoteFileClient.downloadFile(file2download)` and `encoder.encode(im)` do.

Comment: @sp00m how can !fileName.equals("") be covered form !=null? Are you telling that because String fileName=(String)request.getParameter("fileName"); wouldn't return an empty String or just as a general Java String thing?

Comment: You should try to reproduce the problem without all the servlet/http noise. Create a simple Java program (main method) and check if it behaves different.

Comment: I guess you use the internal `com.sun.*` classes, maybe the JDKs just behave different or have different internal details

Comment: @Thihara You're right, use better `if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(fileName))`. My fault.

Comment: @TassosBassoukos any thoughts on how can I handle these on Java? I mean ¿can I look for these parameters reading the source JPG file?

Comment: @home I did, and the result is the same :(

Comment: @EJP, added the code you asked. The code for the method "encode" is part of the JPEGImageEncoder class

Comment: You don't need to decode and re-encode the image. That's where your quality loss is occurring. Just copy the bytes.

Comment: Thanks people. I'll try that on monday @EJP. Have a good day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @EJP and @GuillaumePolet advice, I did this:

```
...
response.setContentType(myContentType);
BufferedImage im = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(contenido));                           
output.write(contenido);
output.flush();
output.close();
...
```

I skipped the JPG re-encoding part and it worked just fine. Also corrected some ugly code using the suggestions on the other comments (I don't post it here because it's really not related to the problem I was facing).

Thanks a lot for your contributions!